# Drop Down Box Value enables Field

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code to run my Dropdown box and field I want to disable when the value is not equal to value in dropdown.

My code is as follows.

```js
document.getElementById('type').addEventListener('change', function() {
  if (this.value == Hijacking) {
    document.getElementById('hijacking').disabled = false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('hijacking').disabled = true;
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="width-qrtr">
  <label>Type of event</label>
  <select name="Type" id="select">
          <option value="">Select Type</option> 
          <option value="Fraud">Fraud</option>
          <option value="Theft">Theft</option>
          <option value="Accident">Accident</option>
          <option value="Hijacking">Hijacking</option>
     </select>
</div>
<div class="width-qrtr">
  <label>Police Station</label>
  <input id="textbox" disabled="true" type="text" name="Test" />
</div>
```

It keeps the field disabled. If i change the values to numerical it works but I need the Value for SQL to be inserted into my DB

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById` works only if you put the corresponding id in defined by `id="..."`. Also to compare string values you have to put them in quotes => `this.value == 'Hijacking'`.

The corrected code looks like this:

```js
document.getElementById('select').addEventListener('change', function() {
  if (this.value == 'Hijacking') {
    document.getElementById('textbox').disabled = false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('textbox').disabled = true;
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="width-qrtr">
  <label>Type of event</label>
  <select name="Type" id="select">
          <option value="">Select Type</option> 
          <option value="Fraud">Fraud</option>
          <option value="Theft">Theft</option>
          <option value="Accident">Accident</option>
          <option value="Hijacking">Hijacking</option>
     </select>
</div>
<div class="width-qrtr">
  <label>Police Station</label>
  <input id="textbox" disabled="true" type="text" name="Test" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Few bugs in your code , fixed as follows:

```js
document.getElementById('select').addEventListener('change', function() {
  if (this.value == "Hijacking") {
    document.getElementById('textbox').disabled = false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('textbox').disabled = true;
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="width-qrtr">
  <label>Type of event</label>
  <select name="Type" id="select">
          <option value="">Select Type</option> 
          <option value="Fraud">Fraud</option>
          <option value="Theft">Theft</option>
          <option value="Accident">Accident</option>
          <option value="Hijacking">Hijacking</option>
     </select>
</div>
<div class="width-qrtr">
  <label>Police Station</label>
  <input id="textbox" disabled="true" type="text" name="Test" />
</div>
```

Comment: Consider mentioning what the bugs were, otherwise your answer is just a game of spot-the-difference.

Comment: Both answers are working here and jsfiddle but when I try it on the live site it still does not allow me to enter text in field if Hijacking is selected. My page is saved as .php could that affect the HTML section I never had issues with that before?